# How do I make the toString() for my custom button work with MouseEntered()?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to access to toString() for my button to be called in an MouseEntered() event and its not working. Any help is appreciated.
Instead of printing the name + " " + x + " " + y on the label it prints something like base.EmptySpace$1@ee2694

```
public class EmptySpace extends JButton {

    private int x; 
    private static int y;
    private static String name;

    public EmptySpace(String text, int x, int y){
        super(text);
        this.name = text;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
                Board.toStringText.setText(this.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + x + " " + y;

    }

    public class Board extends JFrame{

        private EmptySpace[][] buttons;
        private JPanel toolTips;
        private JPanel toStringPane;
        protected static JLabel toStringText;

        private static int lengthy;
        private static int lengthx;

        public Board(int x, int y){
            lengthy = y;
            lengthx = x;

        }
        public void printBoard(){
            int x;
            int y;
            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(lengthy, lengthx));
            buttons = new EmptySpace[lengthx][lengthy];
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthx*lengthy; i++) {
                if(i<lengthx){
                    x = i+1;
                }else x = i % lengthx+1;
                if(i<lengthx){
                    y=1;
                }else y = i/lengthx+1;

                String xString = Integer.toString(x);
                String yString = Methods.getChar(y);



                buttons[x-1][y-1] = new EmptySpace(xString+yString,x,y);
                buttons[x-1][y-1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
                buttons[x-1][y-1].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                buttons[x-1][y-1].setText("");
                buttons[x-1][y-1].setToolTipText(xString+yString);

                pane.add(buttons[x-1][y-1]);
            }
            System.out.println(buttons[1][9].toString());
            toolTips = new JPanel();
            toolTips.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
            toolTips.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            toStringPane = new JPanel();
            toStringPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

            toStringText = new JLabel();
            toStringText.setText("test");
            toStringText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175,50));
            toStringText.setForeground(Color.black);
            toolTips.add(toStringPane);

            toStringPane.add(toStringText);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Trenches");
            SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
            frame.setLayout(layout);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pane, (1280-lengthx*25)/2, SpringLayout.WEST, frame);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pane, (720-lengthy*30)/3, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, toolTips, ((1280-lengthx*25)-200)/8, SpringLayout.WEST, frame);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, toolTips, (720-lengthy*30)/3, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(pane);
            frame.add(toolTips);
            frame.setSize(1280, 720);

            frame.setVisible(true);

        }

    }
```

Comment: `static` is not a viable cross object communication mechanism, especially in a UI environment.  What happens is some one does `Board.toStringText = new JLabel();`?  You've not lost reference to the label that was on the screen.  You should not expose components to possible mis-use, but instead, rely on getters and setters to provide access to the data which you want to expose/mutate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MouseListener is not using the `EmptySpace.toString` method - the call `toString` in the `mouseEntered` implementation refers to the MouseAdapter instance. To refer to the appropriate `JButton` instance and call it's `toString` method, you can get the source of the event:

```
Board.toStringText.setText(e.getSource().toString());
```

Or refer to the outer class instance:

```
Board.toStringText.setText(EmptySpace.this.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it. On a side note, the toString only works as intended for the x value. the name and y value are all what the name and y value should be for the last button declared in the loop. Any idea why? However, the tooltip displays the right name.

Comment: `y` and `name` are class variables because they are declared `static`. Remove this to have them be instance specific.